# Filtering in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items that are categorized and would like to filter using JQuery. I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4H66K/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="leftlist_head">

  <select name="itemage" class="itemage">
    <option value="10">All Item</option>
    <option value="0">Option0</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<ul class="leftlist">
  <li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1">
    <p>Option 1</p>
  </li>

  <li class="todo" id="1012" itemage="2">
    <p>Option 2</p>
  </li>

  <li class="todo" id="1013" itemage="3">
    <p>Option 3</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
function ($) {
  $('.itemage').change(function () {
    var select_val = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).val() == '10') {
      $('li.todo').show();
    } else {
      $('li.todo').hide();
      $('li.todo').filter(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('itemage') == select_val) return true;
        else return false;
      }).show();
    } }
  })
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: @Satpal that works but how can i get it to show all items when all items are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of errors

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemage').change(function () {
        var select_val = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).val() == '10') {
            $('.todo').show();
        } else {
            $('.todo').hide();
            $('.todo').filter(function () {
                return $(this).attr('itemage') == select_val;
            }).show();
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4H66K/5/)